# how to manage file dependencies in a website

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, bower

I am working on a website and gradually it become big. 
I am searching a tool or a method to know file dependencies.

for e.g.

I am using images/js/css files all over in website and before making any change or delete a file I want to know how many files (html,aspx) using that image/js/css file

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build something like this pretty easily. You need to parse the given html into a tree and filter out the external dependencies. There is a module on npm for that called [deps-html](https://github.com/webdeps/deps-html).

Assuming you have nodejs installed, you can install it with:

```
npm install --save deps-html
```

After that you can create a tree and count the dependencies:

```js
var deps = require('deps-html');
var fs = require('fs');

var string = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/your/html');
// build the node tree
var ast = deps.parse(string);
// parse all the dependencies
var matches = deps.extract(ast);
// count
console.log(matches.length)
```

Then you can run it

```
> node count-deps.js
```

You can also get more specific and count the individual assets by accessing the assets `type` property:

```
matches.forEach(dep => console.log(dep.type))
```

Comment: Thanks to reply.

i got an error massage **"const parse5 = require('parse5-utils')"**
do i need to install deps-html global

Comment: Thanks to reply.

i got an error massage 
**
const parse5 = require('parse5-utils')
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\prpatel2305\work\fin_manag
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)**